# собственноручно написанный strcpy выдаёт лишние символы на в конце строки, и копирует размер даже больший чем буфер

Tags: c

сам код функции

```
char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
   int i;
   int n;

   i = 0;
   n = 0;

    while (src[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    while (n++ < i)
    {
       *dest++ = *src++;
    }
   return (dest);
}
```

а фот код тестового main.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src);

int main()
{
    char src[]="текст где больше символов чем в буфере";
    char buf [5];
    ft_strcpy(buf,src);
    printf("%s", buf);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s", src);
}
```

а вот результат вывода в консоль:
текст где больше символов чем в буфере�ре

�ст где больше символов чем в буфере�ре%

подскажите откуда берутся ?
и правильно ли я воспроизвёл поведение функции?

Comment: Приемный буфер слишком маленький для строки. И Вы пишете за пределами массива. А это всегда обычно печаль

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению (или к счастью), с и с++ не умеют "автоматически раздвигать массив, если пишут за пределы". Более того, очень часто даже не могут исключения бросить.

В Вашем случае буфер-получатель имеет размер сильно меньше, чем исходные данные. И копирование за пределы буфера - это неопределенное поведение. В данном случае оно начало перетирать саму строку. Увеличьте размер буфера `buf` до пары сотен байт и все будет работать отлично.

> и правильно ли я воспроизвёл поведение функции?

Скорее всего правильно. Но страшно. В коде с одной стороны попытки супер оптимзиации (бессмысленной) (переменная `n`), а с другой стороны инициализация разделена от объявления.

Смотрите на более "оптимизированную реализацию"

```
char *ft_strcpy1(char *dest, char *src)
{
    char * dst = dest;
    while (*src != 0) {
      *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dst++ = '\0';
    return dst;
}
```

**P.S.**

Как на будущее избегать подобных проблем и быстро-быстро находить проблемное место. Если используется gcc/clang, то в командную строку добавляем `-ggdb -fsanitize=address` (первое - расширенная отладочная информация. Можно даже `-g` или `-g3` писать. Второе - включить проверку адресов. Собственно то, что многие как бы ожидают из коробки. Оно классное, но потребляет дополнительную памяти и немного замедляет программу)

Comment: Так, шепотом - у вас функция 1) не пишет нулевой символ и 2) возвращает указатель на конец строки назначения - куда этот нолик надо записать, а не как стандартная strcpy...

Comment: не то скопировал

Answer (score 0):

Что вы хотите от копирования чего-то туда, где для него нет места?

```
char src[]="текст где больше символов чем в буфере";
char buf [5];
```

Вы же не будете одевать обувь раз в 5 меньше, чем ваши ноги - ну так не делайте переменным так же неприятно...

Ну, а по-простому ваша функция (раз уж она не выполняет никаких проверок) пишется примерно так:

```
char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
    char * dst = dest; 
    while(*dst++ = *src++);
    return dest;
}
```

И еще - ваша функция возвращает указатель на конец записанной строки, в то время как стандартная - на строку-приемник...